# HTML color for all <li> in <ul>

Tags: html, css, web

i need to color all `<li>` in my `<ul>` but li's dont respond to color:black in `.menu ul li (`

CSS:

```
.menu{
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.5pt;
}

.menu ul li{
    list-style: none;
    color: black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">ГЛАВНАЯ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ФОРУМ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ЗАГРУЗКИ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">О НАС</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">КОНТАКТЫ</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you must write ".menu ul li a",because they are anchor tags,http://jsfiddle.net/hbirjand/g2suku8e/1/

Comment: `color:` corresponds to font color.  Is that what you are looking to change?

Comment: just learn basic css https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS (better) and css selectors http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-WF0CF/0/1?curriculum_id=50579fb998b470000202dc8b

Comment: This is a perfect example of something you could debug easily yourself. Do you know how to use the style inspector? If not, you should drop everything until you learn to. The style inspector would quickly show you that the `a` tags are being styled by a built in rule. That would have immediately led you to the conclusion that you need to apply your own color directly to them, rather than to the `li`, hoping the `a` tags would inherit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
.menu{
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.5pt;
}

.menu ul li {
    list-style: none;
}

.menu ul li a {
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: You're applying `list-style: none` to the `a`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! )
thats all my inattention )

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer

You must change the color of `anchor tags` not the `li elements`

Update your code,Use this CSS rule instead

```
.menu ul li a{
    color: black;
}
```

Here is the example

```css
    .menu{
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.5pt;
}

.menu ul li  {
    list-style: none;
   

}
.menu ul li a {
   color: black;
  }
```

```html
<div class="menu">
                <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">ГЛАВНАЯ</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">ФОРУМ</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">ЗАГРУЗКИ</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">О НАС</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">КОНТАКТЫ</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: @obi NullPoiиteя kenobi,Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the color for the 'a' elements inside of your 'li' tags.

```
.menu ul li a{
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have applied the color to the li list element but not the anchor element. browser by default colors the anchor elements to blue with underline. you have to override that property by specifying the color to the anchor element. try..

```css
.menu ul li a{color:black;}

or

ul li a{ color:black;}

or

a{ color:black;}
```

also to remove the underline use the text-decoration css property.

Comment: @obiNullPoiиteяkenobi - I was more interested in telling OP what was causing his issue than just give OP the answer. That way OP will not come back with a similar question next time.And also when you post code in the answer without using the snippet and just having the 4 spaces in front , it does not let me post the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
   .menu{
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.5pt;
}

.menu ul li a{
    list-style: none;
    color: black;
}





<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">ГЛАВНАЯ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ФОРУМ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ЗАГРУЗКИ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">О НАС</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">КОНТАКТЫ</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```